# Ext JS--How to make itemSelector values unselectable?

Tags: extjs, itemselector

Inside my itemSelector's value config, I have set the values like so:

value:["A","B","C"]

A,B, and C are mandatory and thus cannot be deselected. How do I stop these values from being deselected?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the beforedeselect event and return false for these items. It would help people answer question more appropriately if you post your code here.